# Editing a .json file: adding lines in certain parts of the file?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to edit a ".json" file using code or scripts to attach to an installer.

I need it to add in a few lines into a .json config file but I have not found any code or online tutorials on how to do this.

I tried searching for ways to add lines to a normal .txt file but no luck on that either.

What I have found online is appending, but that's not what I need.

Maybe a way to search for certain point of the file to move the pointer to then add in the lines?

I know a little Java but no other coding language.

Is there a way to do it in Java or some small scripts?

Comment: Use a JSON parser to read, then rewrite the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way.  Here is some pseudo-code to give you the concept.

```
JSONObject json = fileRead("myfile.json")
JSONObject objToAdd = new JSONObject();
json.add(objToAdd);

fileWrite(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 7 and your Json is not huge, this is a easy way to add lines:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Automation1\\some.json"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
lines.add(6, "{ \"abc\": 123}"); // as example add data to row 6
Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\Automation1\\some.json"), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

But this technique is hard to maintain.

I suggest you to convert Json to Object, and convert it back to Json file after you adit the Object

Answer (score 0):

Use a json parser library such as [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/). First read the content, pass it to the parser and create a Json Object. Here is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-2_-_Encode_a_JSON_object_-_Streaming):

```
 JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
  obj.put("name","foo");
  obj.put("num",new Integer(100));
  obj.put("balance",new Double(1000.21));
  obj.put("is_vip",new Boolean(true));
  obj.put("nickname",null);
  StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
  obj.writeJSONString(out);   // your writer object, i.e., FileWriter
  String jsonText = out.toString();
  System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Well you can also add one JsonObject to another: `jsonObj1.add(jsonObj)`;